# Processing (java) using Piamge in a class

Tags: java, processing

I need to use a piamge in a class.

```html
class ball {

  String shape;
  int number;
  color col;
  PImage ballimg;

  ball(String s, int n, color c, ?) {
    shape = s;
    number = n;
    col = c;
    ballimg = loadImage("?") // i need this in the parameters of ball to give it to the class
  }
  }
```

I need to give the image in the parameters of the function ball() what do in need to put on the ?.

I hope anyone can help me with this problem

Comment: I suggest you to tag the language you're using

Comment: @DDS it is Processing (java) I put it in the title

Comment: I added it for you (tags are better because people searching for 'java' will look at tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "?"-parameter is the name of the file.

From this [documentation / tutorial](https://processing.org/reference/image_.html):

```
PImage img;

void setup() {
  // Images must be in the "data" directory to load correctly
  img = loadImage("myImage.jpg");
}

void draw() {
  image(img, 0, 0);
}
```

Images must be in the sketch's "data" directory to load correctly. Select "Add file..." from the "Sketch" menu to add the image to the data directory, or just drag the image file onto the sketch window. Processing currently works with GIF, JPEG, and PNG images.

You can use it in an object like this:

```
PImage ball_img;


void setup() {
  ball_img = loadImage("myImage.jpg");


  ball_a = new Ball(ball_img);
}


class Ball {

  PImage ballimg;

  ball(PImage img) {
    ballimg = img;
  }
}
```

Comment: That is what I understand, but how can I pass it to the class when I make a object. The thing like I'm doing in my code with Shape =s and ball(String s, int n, color c, ?)

Comment: @johnwais If you have a follow-up question, please ask that in its own post.